# Java text field foucusing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, textfield

I have a default text set on my textfield, how does the program remove this text when the user focuses on the textfield. Vice-Versa, when the user isn't focused on the textfield the default text comes back.

I was thinking on adding an action event on the TF but that only works when the user taps the enter button whilst focused on the TF. Would a thread would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding a FocusListener to the JTextField. In the `focusGained(FocusEvent e)` method, you could check the JTextField's text and if it exactly matches the preview text, remove it. In the `focusLost(FocusEvent e)` method, you check if the JTextField is empty, and if so, re-add the default text.

```
myTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
    // get text from JTextField
    // if text matches default text, either select all, so user can keep it or change it
    // or delete it --- your choice
  }

  public void foucsLost(FocusEvent e){
    // check if JTextField's text is empty.
    // if so, cal setText(DEFAULT_TEXT) on the field
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers. This one helped me the most, finally learned how to do this, Thanks again to both peoples :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call these functions on your any JTextFields

```
public void FocusGainedEmptyBox(JTextField txt)
{
   txt.setText(null);
}

public void FocusLostFillBox(JTextField txt)
{
   if(!txt.getText().equals(""))
   {
     txt.setText("I am Back");
   }
}
```

call FocusGainedEmptyBox(txtValue) on Focus Gained and FocusLostFillBox(txtValue) on Focus Lost.

Answer (score 0):

Adding/removing text from the text field can cause problems if you ever need to use a DocumentListener on the text field to know when text changes.

For a different solution to this problem check out [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do same as like HTML placeholder ,

```
 private void txtSearchStandardFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (txtSearchStandard.getText().equals("")) {
            txtSearchStandard.setText(" Type Here to Search Standard");
            txtSearchStandard.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        }

    }                                           

    private void txtSearchStandardFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (txtSearchStandard.getText().equals(" Type Here to Search Standard")) {
            txtSearchStandard.setText("");
        }

        txtSearchStandard.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

But Keep in mind about this whenever you are trying to add some another event on this same TEXTFIELD